# How do I print _Decimal32, _Decimal64, and _Decimal128 in C? (Also, what is a Printf hook and how do I add one?)

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64

I'd like to print _Decimal32, _Decimal64, and _Decimal128 with Printf. I'm using Code::Blocks, GCC and MinGW w64. How do I add the required print hooks, and what is the hook for each one?

I tried adding printf hooks. However, I don't know how to this. Can they be added globally?
I've also tried to %D (_Decimal64), %H (Decimal32) and %DD (Decimal128). I'd like to implement all 3.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
_Decimal64 main()
{
    _Decimal64 decim = -9.5;
    printf("%D", (decim));
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it returns D.

Comment: The `_Decimal` types are not specified by C17.  They will make their debut in C2X, due to be published Real Soon Now.  If you are presently using an implementation -- both compiler and runtime library -- that supports them, then you should consult its documentation.  If you are asking about what will be specified in C2X, it is `%H`, `%D`, and `%DD` for `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64`, and `_Decimal128`, respectively, as you seem already to be aware.

Comment: Unless you are talking about *conversion specifications* such as the aforementioned `%H` & co., I'm not sure what you mean by "print hooks".

Comment: Everything you need to know about extending extending the capabilities of `printf` in glibc is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html), if that's your intention.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 They're not using glibc, though.

Comment: I've tried those printf keywords. They aren't implemented in GCC. I'd like to know how to do so. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if the answer for years is "You can't".